# Mathemmatical notation for the summation of the sets based on some other sets values.

Tags: notation, education

Here are the example set values.:

```
X = [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5]
P = [x1,x1,x2,x3,x4,x1,x2,x5,x3,x2]
```

Here `x1,x2,x3,x4,x5` are some numeric values.

What I am trying to do is:

Adding the respective values and creating a set according to the values in `X`

```
C = [3,3,2,1,1]
```

where,

```
C1, i.e. 3, is the sum of all the values of P which are equal to X[1]
C2, i.e. 2, is the sum of all the values of P which are equal to X[2]
C3, i.e. 1, is the sum of all the values of P which are equal to X[3]
C4, i.e. 1, is the sum of all the values of P which are equal to X[4]
C5, i.e. 3, is the sum of all the values of P which are equal to X[5]
```

I thought of something like the following, but it seems like it has flaws:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n P(x_k \in X) + C(x)$$

Please suggest me what could be the best possible output notation for the condition I have mentioned in my description.

Comment: Do anyone have any answers....?

Comment: Yes, anyone do have any answers, but it's the weekend, so you might have to wait to Monday. Also, you have to give people time to make sense of what you're saying.

Comment: It might help us be sure we understood correctly if you put the function in some kind of pseudocode, e.g., `C[n] = 0; for k = 1 to P.length { if P[k] == X[n] then C[n]++ }`

Answer (score 3):

This might be a job for the Kronecker delta function. If $x = y$, then $\delta_y^x = 1$, but if $x \neq y$, then $\delta_y^x = 0$.

Then, if $\mathcal L_P$ is how many elements $P$ has and $\mathcal L_X$ is how many elements $X$ has, then, given $0 < n \leq \mathcal L_X$, we have $$C_n = \sum_{k = 1}^{\mathcal L_P} \delta_{X_n}^{P_k}.$$ Note bene that $n$ is a constant for the scope of the summation, but $k$ iterates and is a subscript for $P$, not $X$.

Others will have better ideas, but my idea is probably the best you can hope for on a Saturday afternoon.

Comment: Why $\mathcal{L}_P$ and $\mathcal{L}_X$ instead of $|P|$ and $|X|$ for cardinality?

Comment: @Chase Because I don't even know about that notation for anything other than absolute value. Go ahead and edit my answer, best case it gets you a couple of points, worst case it wastes a few seconds of your time.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, $P$ is not a set since it can contain the same element several times. Instead it can be described as a function $P : \{ 1, \ldots, N_P \} \to X.$ Then $C$ is a function, $C : \{ 1, \ldots, N_X \} \to \{ 1, \ldots, N_P \}.$ We also have an enumeration $X_n$ of the elements in $X.$

Now $C_n$ should give the number of times that $x_n$ is "contained" in $P,$ i.e. the number of values in the domain of $P$ that map to $x_n$, we can write 
$$C_n = |P^{-1}(\{ X_n \})|.$$
Here $|S|$ denotes the number of elements in the set $S.$